# Select and Count Multiple Group By SQL

Tags: sql

Can someone tell me how to do this in Database?

[image: Select and Count Multiple Group By SQL]

I've tried some sql like:

```
SELECT disastertype, YEAR(eventdate) as year,
        COUNT(disastertype) AS disastertype_total
        FROM v_disasterlogs_all 
WHERE YEAR(eventdate) >= year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 4 
GROUP BY YEAR(eventdate) 
ORDER BY YEAR(eventdate) ASC
```

But, it only shows like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include `disastertype` on our `group by` statement.

```
SELECT disastertype, YEAR(eventdate) as year,
        COUNT(disastertype) AS disastertype_total
        FROM v_disasterlogs_all 
WHERE YEAR(eventdate) >= year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 4 
GROUP BY YEAR(eventdate), disastertype
ORDER BY YEAR(eventdate) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want a count (the column `index`) to be associated with each unique year?

In this case, a possible solution in postgres will be as below.

```
select
    dense_rank() over (order by date_part('year', (eventdate))) as index ,
    date_part('year', (eventdate)) as year,
    disastertype,
    count(disastertype)
from
    v_disaterlogs_all
where
    date_part('year', (eventdate)) >= date_part('year', now()) - 4
group by
    year,
    disastertype
order by
    year asc;
```

In postgres, I have used the function `date_part` to extract the year from the timestamp.

Working solution on [`dbfiddle`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aRezg171XtkwLpGgHYmJWK/1).